# No related Data in Navigation Properties Sharepoint/breeze

Tags: sharepoint-2013, breeze

I'm using Angular, Breeze and Sharepoint2013 for developing a Sharepoint hosted App. In my list i have a column of type User/Group. My Entity defines an navigation properties to sitesuser (.../_api/web/siteuser). On the Networktab of my browser i see that the Sharepoint returns Id an Title from siteuser. Metadata is correct. But I don't get the navigation property populated. I'm not sure from what I read: does breeze.Dataservice.Sharepoint supports navigation properties and related data?

Comment: .../_api/web/siteuser returns a type of SP.User in __metadata. function serverTypeNameToClientDefault in breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint.js on line 383 assumes a name like SP.Data.UserInfoListItem. As siteuser doesn't come from _api/web/listitems the naming convention is different. So the breeze a dapter cannot match client and server type corrently. After fixing up the function the servername is correctly converted to the propper client name and everything works fine.

Comment: so, this will only work when loading SP.User as a lookup List. The sharepoint.breeze adaoter deletes every single navigation property in its updateEntityNode function on line 326. So there is by default no eager load with expand. Remove this line of code leads to several errors. The is no way in version v.0.10.0 to eager load entities with expand - even as the data and metadata is return properly from sharepoimts rest service.